# Numerical integration library interfacing with eigen

Tags: c++, integration, monte-carlo, eigen

I am looking for a numerical integration library like [this one](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwixw-TXttv9AhUzoVwKHXlICoIQFnoECCcQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.gnu.org%2Fsoftware%2Fgsl%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Fmontecarlo.html&usg=AOvVaw1hwqYmuh7FrfQpeIVU6efr). The examples look very appealing but I see that all test functions use very barebones C arrays.

Do you have any recommendations of libraries for numerical integration over functions of multi-variate arguments that bind easily to Eigen?

I suppose in a pinch, one could always use Eigen's .data() methods and element accessors to emulate the C arrays in their examples.

I just think it would be nice to interface with Eigen in a slightly more streamlined way.

EDIT: To make things more precise consider the following problem:

We have a known function $f(\lambda,a)$ and want to numerically integrate over $\lambda$, where $\lambda \in R^{m}$, so we are looking at a high-dimensional integral and possibly need to use Monte Carlo integration or high-dimensional quadrature  methods.

Any leads would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Not familiar with Eigen. Can it not use plain-C arrays? If you had to, perhaps you could write some simple wrappers.

Comment: You should name-drop that you are interested in high-dimensional quadrature or monte-carlo methods of integration. Otherwise integration of differential equations is included in the topic.

Comment: Thank you @LutzLehmann and the wrapper thing is definitely a possibility.

Comment: I think you already gave the answer. Either you get the raw pointers from Eigen using `.data` and use them with the library or you write an Eigen compatible wrapper for the librar, which probably does the same under the hood but allows you to use a more comfortable API in your programs.